# Extremely long compilation time in lualatex (minutes)

Tags: mactex

Compiling the following MWE takes around 4 minutes using lualatex, and 2 minutes with pdflatex.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Of that 2 minutes is spent in starting LuaTeX (between showing `restricted system commands enabled.` and `(./mwe.tex`, then 30s before it prints `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 1`.

It also takes 90s loading expl3.sty, which is also a problem for pdflatex, though that "only" takes 10s to get to `(./mwe.tex`.

Other packages take several seconds to load, but not more than 10.

I assume I have some serious configuration problem, but I can't figure out what it is - I've re-run mktexlsr and fc-cache, lualatex is using about 98% of an i7 core and has plenty of spare memory.

I am using lualatex on MacOS Catalina, but had the same problem on Mojave.

**EDIT**

I am using APFS on an SSD with 40+GB free.

I have no AV etc. running except the OS's own protective software, at the default settings, and have around 75% of total processing capacity free, and nothing is heavily accessing the disk

Comment: well if pdflatex is so slow too it is obviously not a problem specific to lualatex. Do you have any aggressive security software or some unusual file system?

Comment: Probably better to include a word in your document. How long does `kpsewhich article.cls` take?

Comment: I deleted the text to make the MWE as minimal as possible. 

the result of `time kpsewhich article.cls` is  

`/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls` 

`kpsewhich article.cls  28.25s user 6.02s system 99% cpu 34.537 total`

Answer (score 1):

The solution (which I figured out thanks to cfr's comment) was that I somehow ended up with `/usr/local/texlive/2019/` in my TEXMFHOME setting in texmf.conf. I have no recollection of editing that file manually when the problem began, so I presume a broken script mangled it (possibly a bad interaction between MacPorts and MacTex).

What threw me off me was that some packages were loading in only a second or two while others (such as expl3.sty) were much slower, but few were middling, and the slow ones I'd used were packages which were notoriously slow anyway (by normal TeX standards). It appears that it actually was just that packages changed most recently were the slowest. The lualatex format file was virtually the last file in the tree in directory order, hence the absurd startup times.

Comment: From you answer it's not clear to me what was the actual problem. Even if packages from a wrong location had been loaded, that doesn't explain those absurd compilation times.

Comment: it was scanning the full texlive distribution (plus a few other directories) in full without the ls-lR file for every package it loaded, including all the `*-code.tex` files things like expl3.sty load. Certainly fixing that configuration issue on its own fixed the absurdly long compilations.